# SqlAlchemy+Tornado: can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back

Tags: python, mysql, web-applications, sqlalchemy, tornado

i'm building a webapp with tornado+sqlalchemy and absolutely random i got this error

```
     File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1024, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 187, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=exc_value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 822, in _execute_context
    conn = self._revalidate_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 239, in _revalidate_connection
    "Can't reconnect until invalid "
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back
```

I can't figure out how to solve this. I've put all db.commit into a

```
try:
  self.db.commit()
except Exception(e):
  self.db.rollback()
```

That's my class Application.

```
class Application
        [...]
        engine = create_engine(options.db_path, convert_unicode=True, echo=options.debug)
        models.init_db(engine)
        self.db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)
```

but nothing.
What is the best way to configure sqlalchemy and tornado for a web app like mysql+php?

Comment: This is also my problem. With falcon framework + gevent + uwsgi

Comment: @FaraonWEB have you solve this ever?

Answer (score 3):

My way is do rollback on finish, add this to your BaseHandler:

```
def on_finish(self):
    if self.get_status() == 500:
        self.db_session.rollback()
```

Answer (score 2):

I remember having same issuess a while ago. Seems there was some strange stuff related to connection pooling. Disabling pooling seemd to fixed it.
Not the best idea in general, but it worked.

Try passing `poolclass=NullPool` to `create_engine`

```
...
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool
...
engine = create_engine(options.db_path, convert_unicode=True, echo=options.debug, poolclass=NullPool)
```